# Apache Wicket - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer

Tags: java, spring, wicket, cglib, wicketstuff

Need guidance regarding fixing of class not found error at runtime. I have checked all the similar answers, however wasn't able to solve the issue I'm facing.

The project compiles, war file gets deployed on Tomcat successfully without issues
The following stacktrace comes when the first URL is hit, at runtime

`cglib` in my case comes as dependency of `Apache Wicket IOC`, which is dependent on `wicketstuff-restannotations`. `wicketstuff-restannotations` is added as a dependency in my `build.sbt` provided below.

- I did tried to add `cglib` dependency manually as well in `build.sbt`. It shows in `dependencyTree` but still same exception at run time
- Tried adding `cglib-nodep` as well as a dependency
- I tried excluding `cglib` from `wicketstuff-restannotations` and from all `wicket` library dependencies, and then adding `cglib` along with `cglib-nodep` dependency manually. Still same issue.

StackTrace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
    org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:182)
    org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:166)
    org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111)
    org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.inject(SpringComponentInjector.java:124)
    org.apache.wicket.Application.fetchCreateAndSetSession(Application.java:1523)
    org.apache.wicket.Session.get(Session.java:181)org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$2.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:85)
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$2.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:81)
    org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotify(ListenerCollection.java:144)
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onEndRequest(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:80)
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$2.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:85)
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$2.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:81)
    org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotify(ListenerCollection.java:144)
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onEndRequest(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:80)
    org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:266)
    org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:277)
    org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:208)
    org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:307)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
```

relevant and updated build.sbt

*version numbers*

```
// val wicket_version = "9.2.0"
// val spring_version = "5.4.5"
// val spring_security_version = "5.4.5"
// val spring_security_saml_version = "1.0.10.RELEASE"
// val spring_boot_starter_version = "2.4.4"
```

dependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "cglib" % "cglib" % "3.3.0",
    "cglib" % "cglib-nodep" % "3.3.0",
    "org.apache.wicket" % "wicket" % wicket_version exclude("cglib","cglib"),
    "org.apache.wicket" % "wicket-auth-roles" % wicket_version exclude("cglib","cglib"),
    "org.apache.wicket" % "wicket-spring" % wicket_version exclude("cglib","cglib"),
    "org.apache.wicket" % "wicket-extensions" % wicket_version exclude("cglib","cglib"),
    "org.apache.wicket" % "wicket-datetime" % wicket_datetime_version,
    "org.wicketstuff" % "wicketstuff-restannotations" % wicket_version exclude("cglib","cglib"),
    "org.wicketstuff" % "wicketstuff-select2" % wicket_version exclude("cglib","cglib"),
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-csv" % "2.12.2",
    "com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui" % "wicket-jquery-ui" % wicket_version exclude("cglib","cglib"),
    "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-web" % spring_boot_starter_version,
    "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-security" % spring_boot_starter_version,
    "org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-ldap" % spring_version,
    "org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-oauth2-client" % spring_version,
    "org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-oauth2-jose" % spring_version,
    "org.springframework.security.extensions" % "spring-security-saml2-core" % spring_security_saml_version excludeAll(
        ExclusionRule(organization = "ca.juliusdavies", name = "not-yet-commons-ssl"),
        ExclusionRule(organization = "org.opensaml", name = "opensaml"),
        ExclusionRule(organization = "xml-apis", name = "xml-apis")
    ),
    "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "5.3.5",
    "org.opensaml" % "opensaml" % "2.6.4",
    "xml-apis" % "xml-apis" % "2.0.2",
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-dbcp2" % "2.8.0",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.6",
    "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "4.0.1" % "provided",
)
```

Relevant and updated part of dependencyTree:

*Also did a find of `cglib` in full `dependencyTree` and it is available as dependency shown in `dependencyTree` just at one place*

```
[info]   |     |   
[info]   |     +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   |       +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   |       
[info]   +-cglib:cglib-nodep:3.3.0
[info]   +-cglib:cglib:3.3.0
[info]   | +-org.ow2.asm:asm:7.1 (evicted by: 9.0)
[info]   | +-org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
[info]   | 
[info]   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.12.2
[info]   | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.2
[info]   | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2
[info]   | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.2
[info]   |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.2
[info]   |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2
[info]   |   
[info]   +-com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui:9.2.0
[info]   | +-com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui-core:9.2.0
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-auth-roles:9.2.0
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:9.2.0
[info]   | | +-com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:1.9.0
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-datetime:8.0.0-M7
[info]   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:8.0.0-M7 (evicted by: 9.2.0)
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:9.2.0
[info]   | | +-com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:1.9.0
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:9.2.0
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:9.2.0
[info]   | | +-com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:1.9.0
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-ioc:9.2.0
[info]   | +-javax.inject:javax.inject:1
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:9.2.0
[info]   | | +-com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:1.9.0
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-spring:9.2.0
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:9.2.0
[info]   | | +-com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:1.9.0
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-ioc:9.2.0
[info]   | | +-javax.inject:javax.inject:1
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | | 
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:1.9.0
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | +-org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.1 (evicted by: 5.3.5)
[info]   | +-org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.5
[info]   |   +-org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.5
[info]   |   | +-org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.5
[info]   |   | | +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   |   | |   +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   |   | |   
[info]   |   | +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   |   |   +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   |   |   
[info]   |   +-org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.5
[info]   |   | +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   |   |   +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   |   |   
[info]   |   +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   |   | +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   |   | 
[info]   |   +-org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.5
[info]   |     +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   |       +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   |       
[info]   +-org.apache.wicket:wicket:9.2.0
[info]   | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:9.2.0
[info]   | | +-com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:9.2.0
[info]   | | | +-commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:1.9.0
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 (evicted by: 1.7.30)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.4.4
[info]   | +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.4
[info]   | | +-jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
[info]   | | +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.4
[info]   | | | +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.4.4
[info]   | | |   +-org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | +-org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | | +-org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | | | +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | | |   +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | | |   
[info]   | | |   | | +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | |   +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | |   
[info]   | | |   | +-org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | | +-org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.5
[info]   | | |   | |   +-org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.5
```

---

**Update**
There is a strange behaviour I have noticed. I have multiple servers on which the the same code with normal dependencies *(without cglib explicitly defined)* is deployed, with different configurations.
This issue is coming only on one deployment whereas others are working fine.

The configuration files include - `application.properties`, `log4j.properties`, `spring-security.xml`

Let me know if you need more details about this.

Comment: This exception got resolved by adding asm dependency in project. Referenced answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513560/819866. Also, please read the full chat to get more insight into my findings about this issue - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231207/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-and-martin-g

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.wicket:wicket-datetime:8.0.0-M7
```

Why do you use 8.0.0-M7 library with Wicket 9.2.0 ?

Please remove the explicit dependencies for `cglib` and `cglib-nodep` and all exclusions and try again. If it still fails then please the new dependencyTree output.

Comment: It still fails. I removed the both `cglib` explicit dependencies, removed `org.apache.wicket:wicket-datetime` and included `"org.wicketstuff" % "wicket-datetime" % "9.2.0"` to match version. As requested, here's the full dependencyTree - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y889r_Usdiuixl4TkmlVmqN3uBfIgmrA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tried with `org.apache.wicket:wicket-datetime` instead of `"org.wicketstuff" % "wicket-datetime" % "9.2.0"` with versions `7.18.0` and `7.17.0`. Still has same issue. Please check question update as well for a strange behaviour

Comment: Yes, I figured it wasn't you. Sorry! Please paste the complete exception too.

Comment: I have pasted the full exception in question itself. You can check it out from here - https://data.smart360.me/smart360error/ui/signin

Comment: I don't see what could be the problem. I find it amazing that dependencyTree is 300K lines though! To work it around you can introduce an interface for the class that should be injected at `biz.smart360.webapp.security.wicket.BizAuthenticatedSession.<init>(BizAuthenticatedSession.java:81)`. This way Wicket will use java.lang.reflect.Proxy instead of Cglib. Another way is to add dependency to Objenesis. This way Wicket will use Objenesis instead of Cglib for classes.

Comment: Yes it's a big project with lot's of complex dependencies. In your second way, Objenesis should be added explicitly like `libraryDependencies += "org.objenesis" % "objenesis" % "3.2"` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objenesis/objenesis/3.2. I'm trying second way first.

Comment: Try with a breakpoint at https://github.com/cglib/cglib/blob/975e481faf39c91b8ac5b9b3d62822b7c52c5f47/cglib/src/main/java/net/sf/cglib/core/KeyFactory.java#L162 and see whether it fails or not. `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer` means that some of its `static` fields cannot be initialized for some reason.

Comment: Remove `% Test`. It should be runtime dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231207/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-and-martin-g).

Comment: This issue is still there, and it started after upgrade to Apache Wicket 9.x. Things were working fine with Wicket 7.9. In some servers, adding `asm` version `9.1` dependency works and in some verison `8.0.1` works. In some servers nothings works. I really really need your help in figuring out the problem or to find a solution.

Comment: ASM is a dependency of wicket-ioc (https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/676dad7e4403ece1efc9a9603cf3108c7275c231/wicket-ioc/pom.xml#L57-L60). I don't know why you need to add it manually. SBT should add it as a transitive dependency. If this is broken then probably other dependencies are also missing for the same reason.

Comment: Hello Martin-g, I'll try to add all the dependencies and will try that. By changing the ASM versions 8.0.1 and 9.1, I'm able to run it on 2/3 of the servers. When I'll work on 1/3 of servers, then I'll try that, and will let you know